# How to keep textbox color black?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this web page: [rutas.gangatravel.es](http://rutas.gangatravel.es). The problem is that when I put the navigation bar on the page (with bootstrap 3), the names of the text boxes change to white, and if I remove the bootstrap.min.css, the names of the text boxes change to black and it works fine, someone knows how to do to keep the text boxes color black?

Comment: use class="form-control" in textbox

Comment: simply write the inline CSS

Comment: I use another css file loaded after bootstrap. In this file i can make all graphic change.

Comment: Plz provide some code so that we can see whats happening

Comment: the code isnt mine (rome2rio gives you a white label and you cant touch their code), you only can add code like a navbar. And i think there are a label that the name of these label are the same as one of the bootstrap, and when i add the boostram.min.css i got this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using default bootstrap, then go to bootstrap css and change css there.
You can edit the css and can make the theme wahat ever you require.

You can edit in form-control class [Bootstrap form documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)